# Android resource compilation failed-AAPT error-duplicate value for resource

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, compiler-errors, aapt

I have tried lot of solutions but in my case nothing worked. I have searched whole day..
when 'Rebuild Project' I am getting an error like below

```
Android resource compilation failed
C:\Users\admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\dd5cbbcf343124be2329ceb51a9e601b\jetified-shimmer-0.1.0\res\values\values.xml:3:5-948: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/shape' with config ''.

C:\Users\admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\dd5cbbcf343124be2329ceb51a9e601b\jetified-shimmer-0.1.0\res\values\values.xml:3:5-948: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
```

But I couldn't find any files which I used 'attr/shape'.

**Project gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
 }
 apply plugin: 'kotlin'

 allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}


   repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}
compileKotlin {
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
 }
compileTestKotlin {
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
}
```

**App gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

 apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.oxicodes.apple.edropsadmin"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
    targetCompatibility = "1.8"
}
 }

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02'


implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'

//implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'
// Places library
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0'
// PING Place Pickersupport:design
implementation 'com.github.rtchagas:pingplacepicker:2.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
//Image Load
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //for home page
    implementation 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    //volley library
     implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    //Circular Imge
   implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03'
//for textfield
// Facebook shimmer effect dependency
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
//progress bar

//image cropper
api 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
 }
```

I have tried clean, rebuild, invalidate and restart several times but that's not helped. please help me to solve this issue and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

update from `com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar` to   `'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'`

And change the start and stop methods to `startShimmer()` and `stopShimmer()`